# Default cocoa project won't build

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa

I've created an empty OS X project by selecting the "cocoa application".  When I go to build, I get the following error message:

"synthesized property 'window' must either be named the same as a compatible ivar or must explicitly name an ivar"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For whatever reason, the default templates do not build.  The reason is that the property _window is not declared.

```
@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate>
{
    IBOutlet NSWindow *_window;
}
```